# preg_match is replacing wrong

Tags: php, parsing, preg-match

I am trying to write a small parser but it doesn't work as intended:

```
<<IF [10] == [10] FI>>hello<<IF [30] < [10] FI>> # input
<>hello<>                                        # current output
1hello0                                          # intended output
```

I think I did something with the `preg_match` wrong.

```php
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

echo parse('<<IF [10] == [10] FI>>hello<<IF [30] < [10] FI>>');

function parse($toParse) {
  if(preg_match_all("/<<+(.*?)>>/", $toParse, $matches)) {
    foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
      $save = $match;

      $match = str_replace(" ", "", $match);

      if(preg_match_all("/if+(.*?)fi/", $match, $ifs)) {
        foreach($ifs[1] as $if) {
          $if = str_replace(">", "", $if, $gt);
          $if = str_replace("<", "", $if, $lt);
          $if = str_replace("==", "", $if, $eq);

          $if = explode("][", $if);
          if(count($if) > 2 || count($if) < 2) die ("Syntax Error!");

          for($i=0; $i<count($if); $i++) {
            $if[$i] = str_ireplace("[", "", $if[$i]);
            $if[$i] = str_ireplace("]", "", $if[$i]);
          }

          if($gt == 1 && $lt != 1 && $eq != 1) {
            if($if[0] > $if[1])
              $toParse = preg_replace("/<<".$save.">>/","1", $toParse, 1); // here
            else
              $toParse = preg_replace($save,"0", $toParse, 1); // here
          } else if($gt != 1 && $lt == 1 && $eq != 1) {
            if($if[0] < $if[1])
              $toParse = preg_replace($save,"1", $toParse, 1); // here
            else
              $toParse = preg_replace($save,"0", $toParse, 1); // here
          } else if($gt != 1 && $lt != 1 && $eq == 1) {
            if($if[0] == $if[1])
              $toParse = preg_replace($save,"1", $toParse, 1); // here
            else
              $toParse = preg_replace($save,"0", $toParse, 1); // here
          } else { 
            $toParse = preg_replace($save,"Syntax Error!", $toParse, 1); // here
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $toParse;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this line

```
if(preg_match_all("/if+(.*?)fi/", $match, $ifs)) {
```

which checks for the exact 'if' string. The parsed string has 'IF'. It's not a match. It needs to be

```
if(preg_match_all("/if+(.*?)fi/i", $match, $ifs)) {
```

The 'i', after the last regex pattern delimiter, makes the match case-insensitive.
So now it matches uppercase or lowercase letters.